# Axios: Basic auth not working with GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have axios get request with basic auth, but i keep getting back a 401 status code. My code does work if i am doing a post request, so I don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

My backend code:

```
app.get('/api/find-user', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    axios.get('my-url', username, {
        auth:{
            username: 'my-username',
            password: 'my-password'
        }
    })
    .then(resp => {
        res.json({resp});
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error.response.status);
    })
});
```

My frontend code:

```
findUser(user){
    const username = user;
    axios.get('/api/find-user', {username})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Again when i am doing a post to create a new user it does work, but when i am doing a GET request it keeps saying i am not authorized.

Edit: If you feel like downvoting be adult enough to explain why.

Comment: I had the same problem, just installed `qs` and parset the body as: `let body = qs.stringify(params)` as the params were my username and password.
http://npmjs.com/package/qs

Answer (score 11):

You need to do:

```
const usernamePasswordBuffer = Buffer.from(username + ':' + password);
const base64data = usernamePasswordBuffer.toString('base64');
const axiosObject = axios.create({
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${base64data}`,
    }
});
```

Because Axios needs the auth to be "encrypted" with both username and password.

Comment: This really helped.

Comment: could you please write the whole code? what should I do with axiosObject ?

Answer (score 5):

For GET request you don't have a data object. You need send your params in config like this:

```
axios.get('my-url', {
    auth: {
        username: 'my-username',
        password: 'my-password'
    },
    params: { username }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

There’s quite a few potential causes here. I think it might be helpful to state which API you’re trying to access. For instance:

- do you definitely have READ access granted for your account on the API server?
- your POST request isn’t using a password so is your password definitely correct for the GET?

Comment: I'm using the Jira api, https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.10.0/#api/2/user-getUser