# API Integration with Axios - Username and Password PopUp Showing Up

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I've been assigned a task to do with integrating APIs. I've been able to fetch information from the API, but there's a popup showing up, asking me to submit username and password. I have the username and password, but the idea is to log in without the necessity of that popup showing up.

[image: PopUp Image]

Here's the code:

```
const getPlate = () => {
        let licensePlate = document.getElementById('licensePlate');
        let licensePlateNumber = licensePlate.value;
        if (licensePlate.value === "") {
            alert('¡Debe introducir el número de matrícula para poder avanzar!');
        } else {
            Axios.get( * URL GOES HERE * ).then((response) => {
                let plate = response;
                console.log(plate.data[i].make);
                });
            }
    }

<div id="carDataContainer">
     <div id="licensePlateContainer">
          <input type="text" name="licensePlate" id="licensePlate" placeholder="Matrícula - ej. 001 BNDO"></input>
          <button type="button" id="plateBtn" onClick={ getPlate }>Search</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like the resource is expecting a Basic authorization header.

Comment: the alert is being displayed because the `if` is being satisfied also Axios should `axios.get`; can you explain `I have the username and password` part.

Comment: Sure. I have the credentials to access the API and submitting that in the popup works fine. The idea is for that popup not to show up. It's a paid API and my company has asked me to integrate it in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the user/password to axios (looks like Basic auth is expected). Try adding that info to your request:

```
Axios.get( * URL GOES HERE *, {
                  auth: {
                       username: "your-username",
                       password: "your-pass",
                  }
            } ).then((response) => {
                let plate = response;
                console.log(plate.data[i].make);
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Basic Auth

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44239543/7662325

Also if this does not work you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53939140/7662325

Comment: Thanks for your help, Muhammed, already solved it with Ariel's help. Anyways, I checked it for further understanding.